# Sending Google Analytics Events via API: How to get app_instance_id or client_id from Firebase SDK from web client?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

How to get `app_instance_id` or `client_id` from Firebase SDK from web client (not **gtag.js**)?

reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=firebase

I used `firebase/installations`

```
const installationId = await installations.getId(
      installations.getInstallations()
    );
```

but when validating a request with such `installationId` at ga4 api I get:

```
description: "Measurement app_instance_id is expected to be a 32 digit hexadecimal number but was [22] digits."
fieldPath: "app_instance_id"
validationCode: "VALUE_INVALID"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are searching for `app_instance_id` or `client_id` from Firebase SDK.

The easiest option is to allow streaming into your BigQuery tables in Firebase integrations. And then find your `app_instance_id` or `client_id` in BigQuery intra day tables.

In BigQuery you will it under these columns:
`app_instance_id` = `user_pseudo_id`
`client_id` = `user_id`
[image]

Another option is set up a proxy - like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [mitm](https://mitmproxy.org/) and get real log from your application. Then you can easily grep it.

Another option #2 is to install [adb](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/). And use logcat to explore the log with connected device to your PC (preferably Android device. I don't have experience with iOS device)

I hope that helps.